# How can we get reference to current HttpRuntime?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anybody tell me what is this code doing:

```
PropertyInfo p = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetProperty("FileChangesMonitor", 
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static); 

object o = p.GetValue(null, null); 

FieldInfo f = o.GetType().GetField("_dirMonSubdirs", 
                 BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase); 

object monitor = f.GetValue(o); 

MethodInfo m = monitor.GetType().GetMethod("StopMonitoring", 
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); 

m.Invoke(monitor, new object[] { });
```

How did the person get these reflection field names?

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, the code is doing the equivalent of:

```
dynamic o = HttpRuntime.FileChangesMonitor;
dynamic monitor = o._dirMonSubdirs;
monitor.StopMonitoring();
```

The BindingFlags.NonPublic allow, through the use of reflection, accessing nonpublic fields.  Without reflection, the above code would generate a compiler error.

The reflection field names can be obtained through a debugger, or types can be enumerated through reflection.  For instance, to get all public and nonpublic static fields of a type X, you could use:

```
        MemberInfo[] mi = typeof(X).GetType().FindMembers(MemberTypes.Property,
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
            (a, b) => true, // don't filter
            null);
```

Note that using reflection to access nonpublic members is generally considered poor practice, since doing so relies on implementation mechanics that are not guaranteed and that are allowed to change from version to version and between implementations.